# How can I set up a node.js application on a device set up as an access point (using hostapd)?

Tags: node.js, networking, p2p, intel-edison, hostapd

I am trying to set up a node application on an intel edison so that I can communicate with it using a mobile application. I have the edison set up as an access point using hostapd and it has a node application running. If i then connect another device to the access point and point it to the IP address of the edison with the port node is running on then I should be able to access the node application? I can't seem to get this to work, would really appreciate it if anyone has any insight. Essentially I'm trying to achieve a p2p connection without using Wi-Fi Direct, bluetooth or ad hoc.

Thanks!